# How can I make divs with different heights stand on bottom of container div?

Tags: css

I have a number of divs generated with different heights in %. I want the divs to stand on the bottom line of the black container. How can I do this? If I make them absolute positioned with bottom: 0, they will overlap each other.

[image]

Comment: check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/yJbUW/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing flexbox was developed for if you can afford to ignore IE9 and below...

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">50%</div>
  <div class="box">25%</div>
  <div class="box">25%</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.box {
  height: 25%;
  width: 10em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  background-color: red;
}

.box:first-child {
    height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only know one way at the moment and it involves flipping things vertically: http://jsfiddle.net/86c9gbvu/

It's based on using CSS transforms (which is supported).

```css
#container { 
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: black;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-filter: flipv; /*IE*/
    filter: flipv;
}

#bar-one {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50%;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-filter: flipv; /*IE*/
    filter: flipv;
}

#bar-two {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25%;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-filter: flipv; /*IE*/
    filter: flipv;
}

#bar-three {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25%;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-filter: flipv; /*IE*/
    filter: flipv;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="bar-one">50%</div>
    <div id="bar-two">25%</div>
    <div id="bar-three">25%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="bars one">one</div>
    <div class="bars two">two</div>
    <div class="bars three">three</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    margin: 0;
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrap
{
   width: 40%;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
}

.bars
{
    width: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: red;
}

.one
{
    height: 50%;
    left: 0;
}

.two
{
    left: 15%;
}

.three
{
    left: 30%;
}

.two, .three
{
    height: 25%;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pj7knkup/5/

**no css3 (full browsers support).**

Comment: The bars are suppose to be based on %s?

Comment: i fixed it in the code above and and update the fiddle's link. better?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your particular situation, you may probably work around this issue with `margin-top` and `vertical-align`, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjt8sz43/1/). Important is that the sum of `margin-top` and `height` should sum up to `100%`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">f</div>
    <div class="second">s</div>
    <div class="third">t</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
}

.first, .second, .third {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.first {
    height: 75%;
    margin-top: 25%;
}

.second {
    height: 50%;
}

.third {
    height: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One Simple solution is just transform(rotate) the wrapper div 180 deg and set all inner divs to float right.

css:

```
.wrapper-div{
float: right;
position: relative;
transform: rotate(180deg);

}
```